# Stop Infinite Constraint Animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have been struggling to stop/remove an infinite constraint animation after it starts. Basically I have a box that has a constraint of equal height to the main view with multiplier 0.5. The box is supposed to grow and shrink by changing the multiplier to 0.8 and back to 0.5 through **UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat** . Since multiplier is read-only, the only way to animate this is to remove constraint and add it back with the a multiplier. the box is animating fine, but the stopping method does not seem to work at all using the classic ways to stop UIView animation.

[image]

I can stop the animation if I animate **box.transofrm = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 0.8f)**, but doing this instead of animating the constraint itself while Auto Layout is enabled is not recommended.

Here is my code

```
// wired equal height constraint between box and view with multiplier 0.5
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *boxEqualHeightConstraint;
```

.

```
-(void)startAnimation {
        // animation starts fine
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.boxEqualHeightConstraint]; // remove multi 0.5
        self.boxEqualHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.box
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:0.8
                                                                constant:0];

        [self.view addConstraint:self.boxEqualHeightConstraint]; // add multi 0.8
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
           [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

        } completion:nil];

    }

-(void)stopAnimations {

    [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; // not working
    [self.box.layer removeAllAnimations]; // not working


    // I tried replacing the constraint animation, but it is still growing and shrinking indefinitely.
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.boxEqualHeightConstraint];
    self.boxEqualHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.box
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:self.view
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          multiplier:0.5
                                                            constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.boxEqualHeightConstraint];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: `[self.box.layer removeAllAnimations]` works for me. Are you sure `stopAnimations` is being called?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I am sure. The only effect I get is that the box coordinates change and the box will no longer animate around the center of the view, but it is still animating (grow>shrink). [self.box animationKeys] returns key of bounds.size which gets removed by removeAllAnimations, but again that only changes the position of the box for some reason.

Comment: remove the `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` before the animation block, apart from that it works, the stopping jumps abruptly but that is a different issue. You should maybe take a look at changing the priorities instead of adding and removing constraints all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the cause of animation won't stop. My self.box (which is a UIButton) was containing an image.

What was still animating after removeAllAnimations is merely the image inside the box, not the box itself.

so to stop it do this:

```
[self.box.imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```